# Why does my ConditionExpression in PutItem not work?

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

I'm trying to perform a PutItem action against dynamoDB table with `itemID` as Primary partition key and `createdAt` as Primary sort key, with a condition like follows:

```
{ 
    "TableName": "ShoppingBasket",
    "Item": {
      "itemID": {
            "N": "7456473"
        },
        "createdAt": {
            "S": "2001-02-03T04:05:06Z"
        }
    },
    "ConditionExpression": "contains(createdAt, :created_at)",
    "ExpressionAttributeValues": {
        ":created_at": {"S": "Z"}
    }
}
```

The expression is there to ensure that ISO8601 UTC time is provided for the `createdAt` attribute. However it gives me: `ConditionalCheckFailedException: The conditional request failed`

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Using `contains` on items that do not exist yet will always evaluate to false. Instead, please perform input validation on the client side before calling PutItem, checking that `createdAt` is of the correct form.